# can an iOS app include a user-space network device driver?

Tags: ios, iphone, kernel, device-driver

I see Mac [kernel module development](http://www.opensource.apple.com) tips and tricks by Apple but does it extend to IOS apps? Is it possible for an IOS app to load a kernel module behaving as a user space network device for iPhone IOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That information is specific to desktop Mac OS; there is no way to load kernel extensions on iOS.

Comment: I assume same applies to Android apps? Thanks for the response.

Comment: It may be possible on some rooted Android devices, but it's completely impractical and I wouldn't recommend trying. Android kernels are specific to the hardware, and may change with software updates, so you'd need at least one module for every different phone and tablet your application supported.

Answer (score 0):

The changes to networking in iOS11 may enable what you are asking about, although your question is ambiguous as your goal is not clearly stated.